# Make a button show a tooltip / hint when clicked that is different than normal hint in C++Builder / Delphi

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I use a `TButtonedEdit` and setup an `ImageIndex` and a `PressedImageIndex` on the Right Button so that you can at least tell you are clicking on it.

I would like to also provide more feedback by popping up the hint with a different message than normal.    Say it's a ***copy*** button and the hint is ***"Copy to Clipboard"***.   I want it to provide feedback that says ***"Copied to Clipboard"*** when it is clicked.   Is there a built-in way to do that when using C++Builder / Delphi?  In any case, how should that be done?

TIA!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `THintWindow` class with its `ActivateHint()` method to manually display custom hint messages at coordinates you specify.